# Low fan speed resulting in high RAM temperatur on an Intel Server running Proxmox

Tags: memory, fan, cooling, temperature

I recently got an old SR1560SF Server System for dirt cheap. After installing Proxmox VE 5.1 I ran into a problem with the fans:
During boot sequence the fans run at full speed. After booting all the fans are turned off which leads to an RAM temperature of around 80°C. When this happens, the fans starts to spin up but just for a couple of seconds. After that they power down. This cycle repeats every few seconds.

I would like to manually set the speed of the fans, so they at least spin at the minimum speed. I tried using fancontrol but lm-sensors can't find the fans.